# How to use window.location.replace javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

My URLs

```
http://www.mysite.com/folder1/page1.aspx
http://www.mysite.com/folder1/page1.aspx?id=1
http://www.mysite.com/folder1/page1.aspx?id=1&dt=20111128
```

Redirecting Page

```
http://www.mysite.com/folder1/page2.aspx
```

I want to redirect from `page1.aspx` to `page2.aspx`

How to write a javascript in `page1.aspx`?

```
window.location.replace("/page2.aspx");
window.location.replace("../page2.aspx");
window.location.replace("~/page2.aspx");
```

First 2 gave me this.

```
http://www.mysite.com/page2.aspx
```

Last 1 gave me this.

```
http://www.mysite.com/folder1/~/page2.aspx
```

What is the correct way to use?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: looks like you are needing a form of url rewriting?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Include no path information at all, just like in a link:

```
window.location.replace("page2.aspx");
```

[Here's a live example](http://jsbin.com/asupup/2) The example switches between

```
http://jsbin.com/asupup/2   -- The "2" corresponds to your "page1.aspx"
```

...and

```
http://jsbin.com/asupup/3   -- The "3" corresponds to your "page2.aspx"
```

...and so the `2` page uses

```
window.location.replace("3");
```

...and the `3` page uses

```
window.location.replace("2");
```

For more about how URLs (and in particular relative URLs) work, see [RFC3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986). But basically:

- If a relative URL **doesn't** start with `.` or `/`, it replaces the last segment. So:

  ```
      http://foo.com/one/two/page.html
    + bar.html
    = http://foo.com/one/two/bar.html
  ```
- If a relative URL starts with `../`, it replaces the last segment **and** the one above it:

  ```
      http://foo.com/one/two/page.html
    + ../bar.html
    = http://foo.com/one/bar.html
  ```

  Note that the `two` subfolder has been replaced. Multiple `../`s can be used to move up multiple levels:

  ```
      http://foo.com/one/two/three/four/page.html
    + ../../bar.html
    = http://foo.com/one/two/bar.html
  ```
- If a relative URL starts with a single `/`, it replaces everything after the hostname (and port, if any). So:

  ```
      http://foo.com/one/two/page.html
    + /bar.html
    = http://foo.com/bar.html

      http://foo.com:8080/one/two/page.html
    + /bar.html
    = http://foo.com:8080/bar.html
  ```
- If a relative URL starts with `//`, it replaces everything following the protocol, so:

  ```
      http://ex.com/folder/page.html
    + //foo.com
    = http://foo.com
  ```

  (This is handy when loading resources and you want to avoid worrying about `http` vs. `https` and mixed-content warnings.)

Comment: It doesn't. It will load the same page.

Comment: @william: Not if you're not on `page2.aspx`. If you're on `http://www.mysite.com/folder1/page1.aspx` (with or without query strings after it), the above will take you to `http://www.mysite.com/folder1/page2.aspx`. This is the most basic form of relative url.

Comment: @william - if you think about it the second and third URL formats from your question are also consistent with what T.J. has advised.

Comment: which means.. it will not work if my URL is `http://www.mysite.com/folder1` or `http://www.mysite.com/folder1/page1.aspx?id=52` ??

Comment: @william: When you give a simple page name as shown above, it replaces the last segment of the base URL. So if you're on `http://www.mysite.com/folder1/page1.aspx` and the relative URL is `page2.aspx`, you end up with `http://www.mysite.com/folder1/page2.aspx`. If your starting point is different, you'll end up with a different result (because that's the point of a ***relative*** URL). The starting points `http://www.mysite.com/folder1` and `http://www.mysite.com/folder1/page1.aspx?id=52` are different, the second one is deeper in the hierarchy than the first.

Comment: @william: It satisfies the requirements you've stated in your question (all of the three `page1.aspx` URLs in your question can be redirected to `page2.aspx` with the one statement I gave). It can probably satisfy your other requirements if you really understand relative URLs; I've added some notes about those, and a reference. Good luck with it.